# Update the textview text in runOnUiThread is overlapped with previously setted text

Tags: android, textview, android-runonuithread

I want to set the `textview` text with the `mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()` in `runOnuiThread()`. But problem is that the updated text is overlap with the previous set text.

i am new to android and want to change text progmatically after some time that i have given

onCreate method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_content_pop_up);

        imageUrl=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            imageUrl.add("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/"+i+".png");
        }
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerImagevIew=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.image_recycler_view);
        recyclerImagevIew.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ImagePopupAdapter imagePopupAdapter =new ImagePopupAdapter(this,imageUrl);
        recyclerImagevIew.setAdapter(imagePopupAdapter);
        background_Image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_image);
        cross_sign =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cross_button);
        cross_sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
      //  StartAsyncTask();
       // StartTimer();

        handler=new Handler();
        runnable= new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(index<imageUrl.size()) {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl.get(index)).into(background_Image);
                    index++;
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);




    }
```

[image: see image here]

Comment: `textview` is being updated from multiple places

Comment: it is only update in RunOnuiThread .

Comment: I don't think so post code here

Comment: runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                content_viewed_time.setText("");
                                content_viewed_time.setText(SecondsToTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                            }
                        });
                    }

Comment: update your post with your code not in comment

Comment: why are you doing this off the mainthread in a separate thread? also `sleep()` takes milliseconds and not seconds, putting 1 will not be of much help. Log your thread and check how many time it runs.

Comment: I edit the post above . Kindly check it