# How can i change the image source of ImageView after some time progmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to update the source of image view after some time but by changing the source it will overlap with the previous one.
this is the complete code of my activity class. I tried by both runnable and countdowmtimer but the problem is still

[image: enter image description here[1]]

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_content_pop_up);
        imageUrl=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            imageUrl.add("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/"+i+".png");
        }
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerImagevIew=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.image_recycler_view);
        recyclerImagevIew.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ImagePopupAdapter imagePopupAdapter =new ImagePopupAdapter(this,imageUrl);
        recyclerImagevIew.setAdapter(imagePopupAdapter);
        background_Image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_image);
        cross_sign =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cross_button);
        cross_sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        //  StartAsyncTask();
        // StartTimer();
        handler=new Handler();
        runnable= new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(index<imageUrl.size()) {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl.get(index)).into(background_Image);
                    index++;
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }
    public void StartTimer()
    {
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 5000) //10 second Timer
        {
            public void onTick(long l)
            {
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl.get(index)).into(background_Image);
                index++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                SystemClock.sleep(5000);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            };
        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: Why u  use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` or `YourActivity.this` , so first you have to change this and then after check the difference between getApplicationContext() and current this , `YourApplication.this`

Comment: this refer to the runnable or countdowntimer object ,that why i used it

Comment: But `onTick(long l)`  call in mainThread so no need to pass getApplicationContest()  bro

Comment: So what can i use other than

Comment: See my edited answer...

Comment: Hello please check my updated answer

Comment: have you done with my answer?

Comment: yes check it but this error

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'diskCacheStrategy(com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i change the image source of ImageView after some time
>   progmatically

This issue occur becaouse of `Glide` will cashing all image urls so you have to use `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` to resolve  the issue.
I am sure that you not get this issue during app runs very first time.

**Note:** Please check app in real device.

```
Glide.with(DemoActivity.this)
    .load(Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath))
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .into(mImage);
```

**In your case**

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load("")
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true))
            .into(view);
```

For more: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443146/remove-image-from-cache-in-glide-library)

[For more about the glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198856/glide-does-not-resolve-its-method/46073833#46073833)

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'diskCacheStrategy(com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy)

Comment: What is your glide version?

Comment: implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

Comment: For know more about the Glide  see my given links in answer

Comment: Put placeholder before load actual image

Comment: i think this is not glide problem because same problem occur when i update my textview in another activity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230042/update-the-textview-text-in-runonuithread-is-overlapped-with-previously-setted-t

Comment: No the issue is in your index may be 

make index  = 0

Comment: index is initialized with 0 and then incremented by 1 after setting image source

Comment: Not yet , i tried multiple times but issues is still not resolved

Comment: Thanks @ND1010 it was the issue of emulator

Comment: @HafizMuzammilArif if you tell this me first then i told the same about emulator LOL

Comment: @HafizMuzammilArif if you found its helpful to you please right my answer